# Hiding containing element for angular directive from within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following situation with one parent directive and two child directives:

```
<div pane-list>
    <div calc-pane></div>
    <div user-pane></div>
</div>
```

I can use `replace: true` on the child directives, and then in the top level of their template `<div ng-show="showPane">`. This allows me to control whether or not the pane is showing from within the directives I use inside this list of panes - without replying on the parent pane-list directive having anything to do with it or needing to share scope. With `replace: true` I can use these panes inside any kind of parent element with no worries.

Apparently `replace` is being removed, so what can I do instead? I don't see any ways that aren't considerably more complicated. If I can't replace the pane element, I don't see a simple way to be able to show/hide it from within the directive.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Replace will be removed in Angular 2.0, so if you don't plan on upgrading you can keep using it.

Comment: I guess I might have to just do this. I guess you'd have to go about it in a completely different way in Angular 2.0 then.